# SpringBoot + Thymeleaf + SQL, display HTML table from database

Tags: java, html, mysql, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to create site. I have already configured login "/login" and registration "/registration" pages. The main task of this site is to show schedule for every student.
Now I need to display list of subjects on page "/schedule", using HTML-table, according to fields GROUP and COURSE which where picked by student during registration.
I have 14 different tables with list of subjects(1 table - one group of students).

1. Do I need to create @Entity class and Repository for every table?
2. How to show information for students using data from registration?

Controller of page "/schedule":

```
@Controller
public class ShedulePageController {
    @GetMapping("/schedule")
    public String schedulePage() {
        return "SchedulePage";
    }
}
```

Entity for 1 of 14 tables with list of subjects:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "f_fit_c2g1")
public class f_fit_c2g1 {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_f_fit_c2g1;

    @Column(length = 60)
    private String monday;

    @Column(length = 60)
    private String tuesday;

    @Column(length = 60)
    private String wednesday;

    @Column(length = 60)
    private String thursday;

    @Column(length = 60)
    private String friday;

    @Column(length = 60)
    private String monday2;

    @Column(length = 60)
    private String tuesday2;

    @Column(length = 60)
    private String wednesday2;

    @Column(length = 60)
    private String thursday2;

    @Column(length = 60)
    private String friday2;

    public String getMonday2() {
        return monday2;
    }

    public void setMonday2(String monday2) {
        this.monday2 = monday2;
    }

    public String getTuesday2() {
        return tuesday2;
    }

    public void setTuesday2(String tuesday2) {
        this.tuesday2 = tuesday2;
    }

    public String getWednesday2() {
        return wednesday2;
    }

    public void setWednesday2(String wednesday2) {
        this.wednesday2 = wednesday2;
    }

    public String getThursday2() {
        return thursday2;
    }

    public void setThursday2(String thursday2) {
        this.thursday2 = thursday2;
    }

    public String getFriday2() {
        return friday2;
    }

    public void setFriday2(String friday2) {
        this.friday2 = friday2;
    }

    public Long getId_c2g9() {
        return id_f_fit_c2g1;
    }

    public void setId_c2g9(Long id_f_fit_c2g1) {
        this.id_f_fit_c2g1 = id_f_fit_c2g1;
    }

    public String getMonday() {
        return monday;
    }

    public void setMonday(String monday) {
        this.monday = monday;
    }

    public String getTuesday() {
        return tuesday;
    }

    public void setTuesday(String tuesday) {
        this.tuesday = tuesday;
    }

    public String getWednesday() {
        return wednesday;
    }

    public void setWednesday(String wednesday) {
        this.wednesday = wednesday;
    }

    public String getThursday() {
        return thursday;
    }

    public void setThursday(String thursday) {
        this.thursday = thursday;
    }

    public String getFriday() {
        return friday;
    }

    public void setFriday(String friday) {
        this.friday = friday;
    }
}
```

Every table with subjects has name like this - "f_fit_c#g#" where # - number.

Rerository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface f_fit_c2g1Repository extends JpaRepository<f_fit_c2g1, Long> {
}
```

My HTML file of "/schedule" page(with random static data):

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Table 07</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" />
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <div class="small" id="header-scroll">
        <h1><a href="#" style="padding-left: 20px">KNUTE</a></h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Расписание</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Домашнее задание</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Профиль</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Полезные ссылки</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>

<section class="ftco-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center mb-5">
                <h2 class="heading-section">Расписание на первую неделю</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-dark table-hover">
                        <thead>
                        <tr style="text-align: center; width: 20px">
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Время</th>
                            <th>Понедельник</th>
                            <th>Вторник</th>
                            <th>Среда</th>
                            <th>Четверг</th>
                            <th>Пятница</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">1</th>
                            <td>8:20 - 9:40</td>
                            <td>Otto</td>
                            <td>markotto@email.com</td>
                            <td>Thornton</td>
                            <td>jacobthornton@email.com</td>
                            <td>Thornton</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">2</th>
                            <td>10:05 - 11:25</td>
                            <td>Thornton</td>
                            <td>jacobthornton@email.com</td>
                            <td>Thornton</td>
                            <td>jacobthornton@email.com</td>
                            <td>Thornton</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">3</th>
                            <td>12:05 - 13:25</td>
                            <td>the Bird</td>
                            <td>larrybird@email.com</td>
                            <td>Thornton</td>
                            <td>jacobthornton@email.com</td>
                            <td>Thornton</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">4</th>
                            <td>13:50 - 15:10</td>
                            <td>Doe</td>
                            <td>johndoe@email.com</td>
                            <td>Thornton</td>
                            <td>jacobthornton@email.com</td>
                            <td>Thornton</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">5</th>
                            <td>15:25 - 16:45</td>
                            <td>Bird</td>
                            <td>garybird@email.com</td>
                            <td>Thornton</td>
                            <td>jacobthornton@email.com</td>
                            <td>Thornton</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">6</th>
                            <td>17:00 - 18:20</td>
                            <td>Otto</td>
                            <td>markotto@email.com</td>
                            <td>Thornton</td>
                            <td>jacobthornton@email.com</td>
                            <td>Thornton</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">7</th>
                            <td>18:45 - 20:05</td>
                            <td>Otto</td>
                            <td>markotto@email.com</td>
                            <td>Thornton</td>
                            <td>jacobthornton@email.com</td>
                            <td>Thornton</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center mb-5">
                <h2 class="heading-section" style="padding-top: 65px">Расписание на вторую неделю</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-dark table-hover">
                    <thead>
                    <tr style="text-align: center; width: 20px">
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Время</th>
                        <th>Понедельник</th>
                        <th>Вторник</th>
                        <th>Среда</th>
                        <th>Четверг</th>
                        <th>Пятница</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                        <td>8:20 - 9:40</td>
                        <td>Otto</td>
                        <td>markotto@email.com</td>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                        <td>jacobthornton@email.com</td>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">2</th>
                        <td>10:05 - 11:25</td>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                        <td>jacobthornton@email.com</td>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                        <td>jacobthornton@email.com</td>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">3</th>
                        <td>12:05 - 13:25</td>
                        <td>the Bird</td>
                        <td>larrybird@email.com</td>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                        <td>jacobthornton@email.com</td>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">4</th>
                        <td>13:50 - 15:10</td>
                        <td>Doe</td>
                        <td>johndoe@email.com</td>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                        <td>jacobthornton@email.com</td>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">5</th>
                        <td>15:25 - 16:45</td>
                        <td>Bird</td>
                        <td>garybird@email.com</td>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                        <td>jacobthornton@email.com</td>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">6</th>
                        <td>17:00 - 18:20</td>
                        <td>Otto</td>
                        <td>markotto@email.com</td>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                        <td>jacobthornton@email.com</td>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">7</th>
                        <td>18:45 - 20:05</td>
                        <td>Otto</td>
                        <td>markotto@email.com</td>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                        <td>jacobthornton@email.com</td>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

I found a lot of information on similar topics, but I can't find information about working with multiple tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quickly answer your questions,

**1. Do I need to create @Entity class and Repository for every table?**

 Yes you need to create entity and repository for each table in the db.

**2. How to show information for students using data from registration?**

 You will need to fetch the info from the table storing the student details, build a DTO (Data Transfer Object) with the schedule details and all and send it to thymeleaf.

I think you will have to redesign your database itself. The design feels kinda odd.

A better design would be something like this:
[image]